# Generate dates in-between date and date after

Tags: sql, postgresql

Based on the table below

```
date          country   revenue
2020-01-01      US        120
2020-01-01      UK         90
2020-01-01      IT         60
2020-01-05      US        180
2020-01-05      UK         45
2020-01-05      IT         27
2020-01-09     ...        ... 
...
2020-01-13     ...        ...
```

I want to generate the dates in between, by dividing the revenue by the number of days from the date in the current row and the row below.

Example:
Revenue in US on 1 January 2020 is 120. The next revenue date for the US is 5 January 2020. There are 4 days in betweeen. Thus, to make the revenue daily, I would like to divide 120 divided by 4 days = 30.

Output table

```
date          country   revenue
2020-01-01      US         30 (120 / 4)
2020-01-02      US         30
2020-01-03      US         30
2020-01-04      US         30
2020-01-01      UK        22.5 (90 / 4)
2020-01-02      UK        22.5
2020-01-03      UK        22.5
2020-01-04      UK        22.5
2020-01-01      IT        15.0 (60 / 4)
2020-01-02      IT        15.0
2020-01-03      IT        15.0
2020-01-04      IT        15.0
...
2020-01-05      US        45.0 (180 / 4)
2020-01-06      US        45.0
2020-01-07      US        45.0
2020-01-08      US        45.0
...
```

My idea is to use a generate_series, but generate_series requires two dates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similarly to the above reply, the `lead` function will give you the value of the next date.
Also, in case you need to count up to today's date in when you don't have any further transaction, the `coalesce` can substitute the missing target date with `CURRENT_DATE`.

Data

```
create table rev (rev_date date, country varchar, revenue int);
insert into rev values('2020-01-01','US',120);
insert into rev values('2020-01-01','UK',90);
insert into rev values('2020-01-01','IT',60);
insert into rev values('2020-01-05','US',180);
insert into rev values('2020-01-05','UK',45);
insert into rev values('2020-01-05','IT',27);
```

Query

```
with current_and_prev as (
select country, 
    rev_date, 
    lead(rev_date) over (partition by country order by rev_date) next_date, 
    revenue
from rev
order by country, rev_date)

select country, 
    dd rev_date, 
    revenue::float / (coalesce(next_date,current_date) - rev_date) revenue_split
from current_and_prev, 
generate_series(rev_date, coalesce(next_date,current_date), '1 day'::interval) dd;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 create table revenues(dates date, country varchar(20)   ,revenue int);
 insert into revenues values('2020-01-01',      'US',        120);
 insert into revenues values('2020-01-01',      'UK' ,        90);
 insert into revenues values('2020-01-01',      'IT'  ,       60);
 insert into revenues values('2020-01-05',      'US'   ,     180);
 insert into revenues values('2020-01-05',      'UK'    ,     45);
 insert into revenues values('2020-01-04',      'IT'     ,    27);
```

Query:

```
 WITH CTE AS 
 (select *,lead(dates)over(partition by country order by dates)-1 NEXTDATE
 
 from revenues r
 )
 SELECT (CASE WHEN GENERATED_DATE IS NULL THEN DATES ELSE GENERATED_DATE END)DATES,
 COUNTRY,MIN(REVENUE::FLOAT)OVER(PARTITION BY COUNTRY,NEXTDATE)/COUNT(REVENUE)OVER(PARTITION BY COUNTRY,NEXTDATE) REVENUE
 FROM CTE
 LEFT   JOIN LATERAL 
 generate_series(dates,NEXTDATE,interval '1 day' day)GENERATED_DATE
 ON TRUE
 ORDER BY COUNTRY DESC,DATES
```

Output:

| dates | country | revenue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 00:00:00+00 | US | 30 |
| 2020-01-02 00:00:00+00 | US | 30 |
| 2020-01-03 00:00:00+00 | US | 30 |
| 2020-01-04 00:00:00+00 | US | 30 |
| 2020-01-05 00:00:00+00 | US | 180 |
| 2020-01-01 00:00:00+00 | UK | 22.5 |
| 2020-01-02 00:00:00+00 | UK | 22.5 |
| 2020-01-03 00:00:00+00 | UK | 22.5 |
| 2020-01-04 00:00:00+00 | UK | 22.5 |
| 2020-01-05 00:00:00+00 | UK | 45 |
| 2020-01-01 00:00:00+00 | IT | 20 |
| 2020-01-02 00:00:00+00 | IT | 20 |
| 2020-01-03 00:00:00+00 | IT | 20 |
| 2020-01-04 00:00:00+00 | IT | 27 |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=712e85becbd8d2079684a7572343302a)*

Comment: thanks for your solution, however, shouldn't 2020-01-05 for the US show 180/4 = 45? 2020-01-05 for IT --> 27/4 = 6.75?

Comment: My understanding of your question is that you want to distribute the revenue to missing dates. Revenue for  2020-01-05 for the US is 180. If you want it to be 45 then how to and where to distribute other 135? Please clarify. So, that I can revise my answer. Just show me your desired output with that row.

Comment: The answer you have accepted has 1587 rows. Is this what you are looking for? Revenue for 2020-01-05 for the US show 0.3441682600382409 with that query. If it's right then I misunderstood your problem.

Comment: to check whether the values for 05,06,07,08 Jan are correct, I inserted these 3 more lines:
 insert into revenues values('2020-01-09',      'US'   ,     180);
 insert into revenues values('2020-01-09',      'UK'    ,     45);
 insert into revenues values('2020-01-09',      'IT'     ,    27);

turns out that both of your approach and the approach above are correct. However, I'd argue that the approach I accepted as answer is easier to comprehend. 
Thank you for your answer !

Comment: I am not arguing at all. What answer you choose is your choice only. I was just trying to understand. I am happy that you got your answer. Upvote for your such interesting question. Best wishes.